# Missing activity_main.xml in new project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Note: I'm completely new to development in Android Studio.

I downloaded and installed the latest Android Studio (Flamingo 2022.2.1). Then I was trying to follow some beginners tutorials and created a new project (I selected `Empty Activity`).

The project opens and I can see the generated `MainActivity.kt` file. Similar to the tutorials.

Everything seems to be in order except that in my `res` folder there is no `layout` folder and consequently there is no `activity_main.xml` file.

Is this the expected behaviour for this version of Android Studio or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: added screen capture for New Project option
[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Android 2022.2 switched from the classical views concept to Jetpack Compose, which does not require a layout defined in XML anymore. Everything is done in the Kotlin code instead. See [the official Jetpack Compose introduction](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) for more info.

However, this only means that Jetpack Compose is used in some templates for new projects. You are still able to develop apps the classical way. Just choose the **Empty Views Activity** template when you start a new project.

Comment: on the link you provided the instructions are `... In the Select a Project Template window, select Empty Compose Activity and click Next. ...`, but none of the options in my new project windows have `Compose` in the description... ??

Comment: it's OK. Seems like "empty activity" is now same as "empty compose activity". Thank you

Comment: I guess "Empty Compose Activity" was the name of the compose template in previous versions of Android Studio.

Comment: Unfortunately, Android Studio's (developer.android.com) Android Basics Training is way behind and still asking you to set up a New Project using KitKat and eventually asks you to modify activity_main.xml in "Design a Birthday Card app." (the KitKat part's funny but not laughing over here.) Thanks to this answer I went back and tried starting with Empty Views Activity, and it has the file app->res->layout->activity_main.xml! I'm very happy with this answer and hoping to be able to move past this hurdle. I've been stuck on this training course for over a month due to this discrepancy. Thanks!